# User was removed (Jan 2014 issue specific)

Tags: discussion, moderation

I know the question about what happens when a user is removed [is answered here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/811/user-was-removed), but that question was about an incident 2 years ago. Is there any information about the user today? I lost 200 points through this action, just wondering what have caused this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [User was removed](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/811/user-was-removed)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A user requested his account be deleted.  As a result, points received from him are removed from your account.

Evidence of this is still on many questions.

From now, any posts by him will simply show as anonymous user1712.

Comment: Is the link to the user-page accessible for high-rep users?  I get Page Not Found.

Comment: @gerrit yeah it was just to show that it was gone. It shows page not found for us too.

Comment: @gerrit No, even moderators can't access the profile of a deleted user. For users (unlike for posts), deleted means deleted.

Comment: @gerrit What are you trying to look up?